# Can the extra libraries that were needed to compile a program with make be removed after compilation is done?

Tags: cmake, compilation, libraries

For instance, I'm compiling wireshark from its source code.  I've installed a lot of libraries so that I can compile it, like:

`liblz-dev liblz1 liblzma-dev libnl-3-dev libsystemd-dev liblua5.3-0 liblua5.3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libnl-route-3-dev libreadline-dev libreadline6-dev lzma lzma-dev` and many others.

Then I use `cmake` and `make` to configure and compile the package.  Now that compilation is complete and I've done `make install`, can I delete those dev libraries, or will that cause my application to break?

I'm going to guess that I can safely delete any `-dev` packages that I've installed, but anything else would cause the package to break.  E.g. I installed `lzma` and `lzma-dev` to get the feature added in wireshark.  If I delete the `lzma-dev` package, I think I'll be fine, since my compiled program already knows how to use `lzma`.  But if I delete `lzma` that functionality will be broken in my program since it no longer exists.  Is that the right way to look at it?